# Sitefinity 4.4 and Extensionless URLS: Is the sf404.aspx error mapping still required

Tags: iis-6, sitefinity-4

Does anyone know if you still need the sf404.aspx mapping for Sitefinity 4.4?

I'm trying to run a new test SF 4.4 project, but when I try and login the page just gives me the following:

HTTP 404 cannot find /sf404.aspx (this was mapped like that for Sitefinity 3.7)

I then changed the IIS 404 configuration from sf404 to default and now I just get HTTP/1.1 404 Object Not Found.

The project works through Cassini, but not through IIS 6.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Jacques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the sf404.aspx page is definitely only used for Sitefinity 3.x and should not be mapped in a Sitefinty 4 website.

If you are attempting to run a newer version of Sitefinity on IIS6, you need to make sure to use a wildcard mapping so that all requests go through the ASP.NET engine.

This page details everything you need to setup to run Sitefinity on IIS6: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/installation-and-administration-guide/install-sitefinity/configuring-the-iis-to-host-sitefinity-projects

You might also find this blog post helpful: http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/joshmorales/posts/11-02-23/installing_sitefinity_4_on_iis_6.aspx